# How to select only one checkbox at a time

Tags: checkbox

This question might have been answered 100 times before but am still not able to get it.I want to select only one checkbox at a time out of 7.Below is my code.
Please help!

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cbBan = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbBandra);
    cbAnd = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbAndheri);

   checkBoxListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvD);
            tv.setText("");
            if (cbBan.isChecked()) {
                tv.setText(tv.getText().toString() + "" + cbBan.getText().toString());
            }
            if (cbAnd.isChecked()) {
                tv.setText(tv.getText().toString() + "" + cbAnd.getText().toString());
            }


        }
    };

    cbBan.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    cbAnd.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
```

Comment: Cant you just use a radio button ? its it purpose .

Comment: 1. What language (tag appropiately)
2. Why not use a radio button? The functionality you describe is its only purpose.

Comment: Am new to Android Programming and i have been given the above task..I dont have any idea about the radiobuttons.
Could you just edit my codes and show me how its done using radio?